# Did we ever see a Borg drone with a chunk of its face torn off?

Tags: star-trek, borg, episode-identification

I came across the following image while Googling “human robot hybrid” (don't ask), and upon further investigation found it pops up on a few random blogs but always without attribution or further explanation.

[image: Borg with hole in its face]

It appears to be a Borg drone with a big hole in its face.

Did this ever happen in an episode?? Or must it be some behind-the-scenes snap, or convention/recreation model?

Comment: I thought "Imperfection" were a good candidate, but I can't find a match.

Comment: [This news site](http://newatlas.com/silicon-computer-chips-implanted-in-living-cells/14560/) credits it to a "gundampilotspaz" on Flickr, but the account does not seem to be active.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but that looks more like Borg tech jutting out from the face, not a hole torn into it.

Comment: @Xantec: Oh, hah, maybe.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: Easy mistake to make in a black-and-white image.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots: I've always found it remarkable how different the image can look depending on how it's grayscaled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This news site](http://newatlas.com/silicon-computer-chips-implanted-in-living-cells/14560/) credits it to a "gundampilotspaz" on Flickr. The account does not seem to exist, but doing some cross-site searches indicates that someone by that name took some pictures of Borg models at the [Star Trek: The Experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Experience) attraction at the Las Vegas Hilton in Paradise, Nevada. It would probably be associated with the "The Borg Invasion 4-D" display. Unfortunately, it closed in 2008. Here are a few of the images from various sources so you can judge if they look like they would match:

[image: Borg in display cases] [image: Part of the filming of a Federation officer being assimilated] [image: More borgs in a display case] [image: The backwall here looks like the "floor" in the picture above, but it's more Borg in a display case]

After Xantec mentioned that it looked less like a hole than an implant, I took another look at the images, particularly the third one [from this review](http://myworldreviews.com/reviews/Star_Trek_The_Experience-114.html), and I think it's the left-most (audience left, not stage left) of the three in the display case (apparently along the queue), with the black patch and the silverish circular bit over its eye. Here are cropped sections side by side.

[image: Side by side of images]

Here is a video of the movie:

Comment: Ahem; http://myworldreviews.com/reviews/Star_Trek_The_Experience-114/figurebig-385.jpg

Comment: @Valorum: Thank you. I had only run into the smaller verison.

Comment: I agree it is the source.   Suggest a cropped section of the larger image @Valorum linked side by side with the original image.   Or hand drawn red circles.

Comment: Yup. Clearly slightly different angles, but recognizable as the same model.

Comment: Excellent work everybody!